Express unable to route to 404 using wildcard *
I am using  express and i want to redirect to 404 when the page is not found. Somehow it is always routing to /dashboard when I insert the invalid URL in browser. Not sure How to add the check fusing wildcard operation
I have tried *, /**, /*
Here is my code which goes in index-routes.js file
//Base routes
router.get('/*', async (req, res, next) => {

const data = {
  title: 'MyApplication',
  appVersion: req.appVersion || '',
  name: secure.session.name || '',
  email: secure.session.email || '',
  userId: '',
  module: secure.session.homeModule,
  appPath: secure.session.homeModuleUrl,
  sessionAge: env.sessionAge,
  isDev: env.isDevelopment,
  uiAppUrl: env.uiAppUrl,
  appUrl : env.appUrl,
  froalaKey: env.froalaKey,
  pusherKey: env.pusherKey,
  pusherCluster: env.pusherCluster,
  nonce: res.locals.nonce,
};
if (req.path === '/') {
  const account = new Account(req.db);
  const user_settings = await account.getUserSettings(
    new ObjectId(session.userId)
  );
  data.homeUrl = user_settings.homeUrl || '/dashboard';
}
    res.render('index', data);
});

Now i want to update code to something like this
Now i have tried this in my app.js file where I injected routes and want to route to 404 on invalid routes. I adding app.all before my index routes and it was redirecting all pages to 404
 app.use('/', index_routes);
  app.all('*', function(req, res) {
      res.status(404).json({
          success: false,
          data: '404'
      })
  });

What should I try here?

Add this middleware before your index routes
app.all('*', function(req, res) {
    res.status(404).render('404'); // Assuming you have a 404 view
});


If I add before index routes it re-directs all pages to 404
